# Return CGPoints from a function

Tags: cgpoint

I have another question about passing `CGPoint` in junctions:

```
(CGPoint[]) displayPoints:(CGPoint) startPoint 
                        withEnd:(CGPoint) endPoint
                 withBaseRotate:(Boolean) baseRotate {

// do some stuf with four or six points
// create a array of the points and return - it


    CGPoint ourPoints[] = {
        CGPointMake(point1.x, point1.y),
        CGPointMake(point2.x, point2.y),
        CGPointMake(point3.x, point3.y),
        //... some more points
    } ;

  return ourPoints[];
}
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

Have to return a pointer to where it is stored at in memory

```
(const CGPoint *) displayPoints:(CGPoint) startPoint 
                  withEnd:(CGPoint) endPoint
           withBaseRotate:(Boolean) baseRotate {

    CGPoint ourPoints[] = {
        CGPointMake(point1.x, point1.y),
        CGPointMake(point2.x, point2.y),
        CGPointMake(point3.x, point3.y),
        //... some more points
    } ;

  return ourPoints;
}
```

If you look at the signature of CFContextAddLines, you'll see that is what they're using.  Now the compiler will throw a warning for returning a pointer to memory... so I'm not sure if this is the preferred way but it answers your question.